# django running unittest fail while one of my app named "apps", but "runserver" works

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a django-project, its apps like this:

[image]

In apps/apps, there're views/models/urls as usual.

"runserver" works fine with command

```
./manage.py runserver --settings=mysettings 0:8000
```

But when I tried to run unittest with command below, ImportError met.

```
./manage.py test --settings=mysettings
```

========================================

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lethe/.envs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 413, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Users/lethe/.envs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Users/lethe/.envs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Users/lethe/PycharmProjects/phone-buddy-oms/src/apps/downloads/tests/test_downloads_models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apps.models import (AppSource, AppCategory, App, Merchant, Apk)
ImportError: cannot import name Apk
```

It seems that django unittest frame cannot tell apps or apps/apps, I've tried to use django-nose to run but fail with similar errors.

Is there a solution except change the name of 'apps/apps'? thank you.

Comment: What's your Python path when you run `runserver` and when you run `test` (it's available in `sys.path`)? I'd strongly recommend renaming either your root apps folder, or the "apps" app, but we can probably get around it by making sure your path is set up correctly.

Comment: It looks as if you're using pycharm from that screenshot. [This page](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-django-test.html) may help.

Comment: which version of django?

Comment: I'm using virtualenv, my sys.path includes my project directory: ''myproject/src', while all python files are under src/apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project home shouldn't have an **init**.py file, unittest mistakes your project home for a module and tries to load the tests from there but fails (because it has the same name as the app in INSTALLED_APPS).