# Basic Tests in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I am making a Test in my django project, but when I execute the test in the console I get the following output

```
(course)bgarcial@el-pug:~/python_Devel/course/proyecto_clase2$ python manage.py test app
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
E
======================================================================
ERROR: proyecto_clase2.app.tests (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: proyecto_clase2.app.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 252, in _find_tests
     module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 230, in _get_module_from_name
      __import__(name)
 ImportError: No module named app.tests


 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Ran 1 test in 0.000s

 FAILED (errors=1)
 Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
(course)bgarcial@el-pug:~/python_Devel/course/proyecto_clase2$
```

My file tests.py is the following:

```
from django.test import TestCase

from .models import Categoria,Enlace
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your tests here.

    class SimpleTest(TestCase):
        def test_es_popular(self): 
            categoria = Categoria.objects.create(titulo='Categoria de prueba') 
            usuario = User.objects.create_user(username='julian', password='barbas')
            Enlace.objects.create(titulo='Prueba',enlace='http://ieee-wie.co', votos=0,
                              categoria=categoria, usuario=usuario)
```

What thing can be happenning in relation to the module that has been failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem and was able to solve it using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987353/django-running-unittest-fail-while-one-of-my-app-named-apps-but-runserver-w?rq=1). The test runner is probably trying to import your tests from the project directory rather than the module they are part of.

Try running a single test explicitly with:

```
$ python manage.py test app.tests.SimpleTest
```

Then try removing the `__init__.py` file from your project directory if you have one there (the directory under which your `manage.py` file is stored but **not** the directory where your settings are stored).

Comment: the test works for me as you says me. I review the link taht you refer me, but.. I don't understand still .. why I should add the name_of_my_app.tests.TestClass ?

Comment: when you run a single test explicitly you tell the test runner exactly where to find the test. when you just do `$ python manage.py test` then the test runner tries to find all your tests in your project for you. however, it will fail to find the tests if you have an `__init__.py` in your project directory when your project directory has the same name as an installed app. does this help clarify at all?

Comment: +1 I just realised, simple `__init__.py` along with `manage.py` will make you fall into this stupid error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the current (dev, 1.7) [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/):

> Changed in Django 1.6:
>
> Previously, Django’s default test runner only discovered tests in
>   `tests.py` and `models.py` files within a Python package listed in
>   `INSTALLED_APPS`.

So, looks like you are using django < 1.6 and, your tests cannot be found since you don't have `tests.py` under `app` package.

Now you have several ways to fix the problem:

- rename `test.py` to `tests.py` - django will find your tests in `tests.py`
- upgrade to django 1.6 - django will find your tests in `test.py`
- switch to the third-party test runners, like [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) ([django_nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose) package will definitely help). Django (with the help of nose test discovery) will find your tests in `test.py`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Alecxe, my file is named  tests.py, I am wrong when says before that was test.py. Really is tests.py and my django version is 1.6.2

Comment: @BernardoGarcia hm, do you have `app` listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, my app is listed in the INSTALLED_APPS directive in settings.py file